# Maintaining separate sets of custom objects for different apps

Tags: custom-object, app, app-development, org

After working on an app for some time, I created a second app where I wanted to have an entirely new set of custom objects. However in the setup mode of the 2nd app I can still see the cutsom objects from the first app. Is there a way to have a separate set of custom objects in the setup area of each app?

Comment: Do you mean in the setup area of Salesforce or someplace else?

Comment: If you are talking about internal to SF, then I guess I dont see the issue.  Why is it an issue that you can 'see' the objects in the setup screen.  You don't have to use them.  Maybe I am misunderstanding the question...?

Comment: No I'm basically trying out a different version of the app that might have many of the same object names, so I want to prevent confusion

Comment: You could try to recreate the objects in a new developer org ?

Comment: Could you please point me to a link that would tell me how create a new developer org? Can I do it with the same ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Salesforce, multiple apps in the same org basically functions as a container for the tabs you want to display, and can also serve as an access gate (as you can control what apps users have access to through their profile). But on the backend setup, all the apps in the org share the same set of custom objects and custom fields that you create.

If you do want a fresh start, with none of the custom objects you have already created, then I would recommend starting another developer org, and maintaining them there. You can then use the various migration tools Salesforce provides to merge any changes.

Comment: @user1909491 can you provide the navigation how to achieve requriment.

Comment: @sfdc_ninja has provided the link in a separate answer. You will need to use a separate ID from the existing org. What I typically do is: Org A userID is user@domain.com, then my Org B username is user+1@domain.com, but you can use any naming convention as long as it is unique.

Comment: Would that mean basically having to re-register to Salesforce?

Comment: Basically, yes. You are signing up for a new developer org with a different Id.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Mark Masterson's answer and to answer your question in the comments...

You can create a new developer Org, but it will not have the same ID, it will have a new ID.  For information on how to create a new developer org, take a look here, should tell you everything you need to know

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Developer_Edition